# How to turn off Portal 2 Xbox skin?

Tags: portal-2

I got one of the preorder DLC packs for Portal 2 on Xbox 360 that gave the Robots skins that could be applied to them. I was wondering if their was a way to turn off this skin without deleting the actual DLC content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is - equip anything such as a hat or flag or skin.** The devs have [not shown the love for the unfortunates plagued with the ill-designed roll-cage DLC](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1851758&page=1). [They said they would fix it](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1855019), but I don't see it in my inventory so I'm not leaving my co-op bots bare.

If you're too cheap to buy robot enrichment bobbles and doodads (I know I am), the free ones (which happen to be easy to get) are:

**Bionic Beanie:** Earn the “Lunacy” Achievement. You’ll get this achievement, and the unlockable, when you **complete Portal 2′s single player campaign**.

**WCC Flag:** Earn the “High Five” Achievement, which you get for **completing the first co-op course** in Portal 2.

Comment: We missed the 1 year anniversary of Valve's failed promise by 3 days :(